# Xamarin Android getting Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, androidx

After migrating to AndroidX and updating all AndriodX packages to latest, builds would fail showing me three similar errors in build-generated XML files in `obj` folder:

1. `\obj\Debug\100\lp\117\jl\res\values\values.xml`: Found tag id where item is expected

The XML file content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <id name="view_tree_lifecycle_owner"/>
</resources>
```

2. `\obj\Debug\100\lp\121\jl\res\values\values.xml`: Found tag id where item is expected

The XML file content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <id name="view_tree_saved_state_registry_owner"/>
</resources>
```

3. `\obj\Debug\100\lp\123\jl\res\values\values.xml`: Found tag id where item is expected

The XML file content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <id name="view_tree_view_model_store_owner"/>
</resources>
```

After looking for solutions online, I just changed `<id name="...` to `<item type="id" name="...` in each  of the generated files and the build succeeded (even though I have to re-do this every time I clean/rebuild).

However, right after the app's splash screen, it app crashes showing the following exception:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to get provider androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwnerInitializer" on path: DexPathList...

I looked that up and found many solutions suggesting enabling and/or configuring multi-dex, none of which ever worked.

The problem **occurs only when** linking is set to `Sdk Assemblies Only` or `Sdk and User Assemblies`.

Here's some of the configuration that didn't work with me:

- I have tried enabling/disabling  `Enable Multi-Dex` in `Android Options` tab in project properties.
- I have tried setting `android:name` attribute in `application` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` to `androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication`.
- I have tried to make `MainApplication` class inherit from `Android.Support.MultiDex.MultiDexApplication` (defined in [XamarinLibrary.Xamarin.Android.Support.Multidex](https://www.nuget.org/packages/XamarinLibrary.Xamarin.Android.Support.Multidex/1.0.3)) instead of `Android.App.Application`.
- I have tried to make `MainApplication` class inherit from manually created binding for AndroidX MultiDexApplication like this:

`MultiDex.cs`:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;

using Java.Interop;

using System;

namespace OnePoint
{
    [Register("androidx/multidex/MultiDex", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
    public sealed class MultiDex : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        private static readonly JniPeerMembers _members = new XAPeerMembers("androidx/multidex/MultiDex", typeof(MultiDex));

        internal static IntPtr class_ref => _members.JniPeerType.PeerReference.Handle;

        public override JniPeerMembers JniPeerMembers => _members;

        protected override IntPtr ThresholdClass => _members.JniPeerType.PeerReference.Handle;

        protected override Type ThresholdType => _members.ManagedPeerType;

        internal MultiDex(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        [Register("install", "(Landroid/content/Context;)V", "")]
        public static unsafe void Install(Context context)
        {
            try
            {
                JniArgumentValue* ptr = stackalloc JniArgumentValue[1];
                *ptr = new JniArgumentValue(context?.Handle ?? IntPtr.Zero);
                _members.StaticMethods.InvokeVoidMethod("install.(Landroid/content/Context;)V", ptr);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }

        [Register("installInstrumentation", "(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Context;)V", "")]
        public static unsafe void InstallInstrumentation(Context instrumentationContext, Context targetContext)
        {
            try
            {
                JniArgumentValue* ptr = stackalloc JniArgumentValue[2];
                *ptr = new JniArgumentValue(instrumentationContext?.Handle ?? IntPtr.Zero);
                ptr[1] = new JniArgumentValue(targetContext?.Handle ?? IntPtr.Zero);
                _members.StaticMethods.InvokeVoidMethod("installInstrumentation.(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Context;)V", ptr);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`MultiDexApplication.cs`:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Runtime;

using Java.Interop;

using System;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Register("androidx/multidex/MultiDexApplication", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
    public class MultiDexApplication : Application
    {
        internal static readonly JniPeerMembers _members =
            new XAPeerMembers("androidx/multidex/MultiDexApplication", typeof(MultiDexApplication));

        internal static IntPtr java_class_handle;

        private static IntPtr id_ctor;

        [Register(".ctor", "()V", "", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
        public MultiDexApplication()
            : base(IntPtr.Zero, JniHandleOwnership.DoNotTransfer)
        {
            if (Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            try
            {
                if (GetType() != typeof(MultiDexApplication))
                {
                    SetHandle(
                        JNIEnv.StartCreateInstance(GetType(), "()V"),
                        JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                    JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance(Handle, "()V");
                    return;
                }

                if (id_ctor == IntPtr.Zero)
                    id_ctor = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(class_ref, "<init>", "()V");
                SetHandle(
                    JNIEnv.StartCreateInstance(class_ref, id_ctor),
                    JniHandleOwnership.TransferLocalRef);
                JNIEnv.FinishCreateInstance(Handle, class_ref, id_ctor);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }

        protected MultiDexApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer)
            : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {
        }

        internal static IntPtr class_ref => JNIEnv.FindClass("androidx/multidex/MultiDexApplication", ref java_class_handle);

        protected override IntPtr ThresholdClass => class_ref;

        protected override Type ThresholdType => typeof(MultiDexApplication);

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            MultiDex.Install(this);
        }
    }
}
```

- I have tried cleaning/rebuilding the solution.
- I have tried restarting Visual Studio.
- I have tried executing `update-package -reinstall` in Visual Studio's package manager console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this problem was misleadingly reported by `r8` dex compiler. When I changed the dex compiler to `dx`, it reported a different compilation error: `invalid opcode ba - invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26 (currently 13)` even though the `min-sdk-version` was not `13`. After looking up the latter error, thanks to [this thread](https://feedback.telerik.com/xamarin/1458623-invalid-opcode-ba-invokedynamic-requires-min-sdk-version-26-currently-13-build-error-after-upgrading-to-version-2020-1-318-1), I was able to resolve the problem by downgrading `Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser` to version `1.0.0.1` (the latest version before `1.2.0` [where the problem was introduced](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/78)). After downgrading the mentioned package, I could successfully compile and run with either `dx` or `d8`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem but only for the first XML that you mentioned (`<id name="view_tree_lifecycle_owner"/>`)

I found an answer that worked for me (Release configuration with linking set to `Sdk Assemblies Only`)

In the Android project properties, I enabled the "use incremental Android packaging system" checkbox under "Android Options." and that solved the issue.

I found the solution in [this](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/issues/152) thread.

Comment: Thanks for answer. "use incremental Android packaging system"

Comment: I could resolve this issue manually, but I would still have it on the build pipeline. Thanks to your answer, it's now not occurring on the build pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

I had to set the following

```
<AndroidUseAapt2>true</AndroidUseAapt2>
```

in the Android.csproj file to get this to work. (it was set to false and appears multiple times in the csproj file).